# Docker for Windows & MS-Access database & Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Tags: c#, docker, ms-access, oledb

I need to setup a docker container in which a legacy application needs to connect to an MS-Access 2003 DB. The connectionstring to the DB is embedded in the application itself and therefore cannot be changed. So I cannot change the provider to be `ACE.OleDb` either.

I have created docker images based on …

- microsoft/dotnet-framework
- microsoft/windowsservercore
- microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express

… but I always get the same result when running the legacy application on the container.

> The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I also tried to register the `msjetoledb40.dll` in SysWow64 with the following command in the container ...

> C:\Windows\SysWow64\regsvr32 Msjetoledb40.dll

... but does not seem to work either.

I have also installed the Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable (2007, 2010 & 2016) in 32 and 64 bit (AccessDatabaseEngine.exe & AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe) but always get the same error as mentioned above.

[2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi David,
I developed a simple app that connects to MS-Access-2003 db where I can change the connectionstring. Fails with Jet.Oledb and succeeds with Ace.Oledb provider.
But as I mentioned in the original post I cannot change the connectionstring of the legacy app since it is embedded in the dll. I know this can run in a 64bit OS since it works fine in my dev-comptuer using Windows 10 64bit and my dev.computer has already registered the msjetoledb40.dll in SysWow64. This is the real issue since I cannot register this dll in any Win-Docker-Container or even in a Hyper-V WinServerCore VM. Tx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED:

I found a '[Jet 4.0 Service Pack 8 (SP8) for Windows 95/98/NT 4.0 (KB829558)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7151)' package.

Copied the **Jet40SP8_9xNT.exe** to the container and added this statement to the **dockerfile**

```
RUN Jet40SP8_9xNT.exe /Q
```

Comment: I have tried to use this but the my dockerfile just gets stuck

Comment: This worked for me. Spent a long time trying to run a x86 ASP.NET app that had some very old dependencies inside of a docker container. The link above is dead but I was able to find a download for it at https://api.256file.com/download/8510_jet40sp8_9xnt.exe.